# iOS transitioning views using animation blocks

Tags: ios, uiview, core-animation

I am trying to animate between 2 subviews. At the moment I've tried different options, each with their own side effects.

The application is a small game with a skills subview, an inventory subview, and a status subview. I want to animate between the skills and the inventory views while leaving the status subview on the bottom of the main view. Below I've listed my various attempts and the side effects from them.

- Animate from `animateWithDuration

  - `[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0.3 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight | UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn animations:^{
        skillView.hidden = NO;
        inventoryView.hidden = YES;
    }completion:NULL];`
  - No transitions seems to take place. The views just pop in.
- Animate from `transitionFromView`

  - `[UIView transitionFromView:inventoryView toView:skillView duration:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight completion:^(BOOL finished){
        inventoryView.hidden = YES;
    }];`
  - The transition is done perfectly, but the status view transitions with the  other views. Almost as if the main view is animating with everything.

The views are loaded into the main view just hidden in the background and they used to just pop into the main window. However, I would like to animate between the views to have a better application flow. I've seen people remove and add to the main view, but I'm hoping that setting the subviews to be visible/invisible should have the same effect.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try using the `UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews` option with the `transitionFromView:...` method? (eg. add both views but keep one hidden - then call the `transitionFromView:...` with that option)

Comment: Would I have to add both views in the animation block? If so then how would it work if I have to switch back? would I be able to call a similar setup or do I have to remove bother views and add them back in?

Comment: That option (`UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews`) changes how `transitionFromView:...` works. Typically that method actually modifies the `fromView`'s parent's view hierarchy (removing the `fromView` and adding the `toView`). To use the option I cited, Simply make sure both views are in the view hierarchy already before calling the method - and make sure they are above the status subview you mentioned. To go the opposite direction, simply flip the arguments... toView becomes fromView and vice-versa.

Comment: It still looks as if the whole window is being flipped while flipping the sub views.

Comment: Would it be possible to put both views inside a container view? e.g. A UIView which only contains those two views you want to animate?

Comment: It is possible, but how would it be any different than what is currently setup? Instead of me trying to flip 2 subviews, I'd have to flip a subview containing 2 subviews? Just not picturing how flipping one subview could be any different than flipping 2.

Comment: No - still flip your two subviews - but I believe the transition will be isolated to their immediate shared container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Animation doesn't know how to animate those views apart from their direct ancestor (parent).

Break them into a single container view.

Eg:

Instad of this:

```
Parent
 - Other View
 - View A
 - View B
 - Other View
```

Have this:

```
Parent
 - Other View
 - Container
   - View A
   - View B
 - Other View
```

See comments to question for more detail.